# How to fix the Broken SD Card

Tags: partition-recovery, micro-sd-card

I seem to have broken my micro SD card.The partition names in the disk-utility shows unknown partition.

Can some one assist on how to go about recovering the data from it or fixing it?
Attached are the snapshot.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried fixing the format? Does it show up as currupt?

Comment: I didnt get what you mean.

Comment: You can try clicking "Format drive", to format it, maybe that fixes the problem. Note that this will delete all data.

Comment: I need data otherwise I could formatted it already, ;)